# Laravel empty request

Tags: php, xml, laravel, rpc, xml-rpc

I am trying to figure out working with xml-rpc with Laravel 5.4
I am using Open HttpRequester for sending xml request to Laravel,
It returns 200 OK status code, but i am not able to process the request data.

I ve got the request routed to a controller with just one method (testMethod), with following content:

```
public function testMethod(Request $request) {        
    $req = xmlrpc_decode_request($request, $method);
    print_r($req);
    print_r($request->toArray());           
}
```

my XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodCall>
    <methodName>testMethod</methodName>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value>
                <string>Test value 1</string>
            </value>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodCall>
```

this request only return a blank array.

**What am i doing wrong?**

EDIT:

Adding some additional code.

Route:

```
Route::post('/request', 'RequestController@testMethod');
```

Raw request:

```
POST http://localhost/laratest/public/index.php/request
User-Agent: /
Host: localhost
Content-Type: text/xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodCall>
    <methodName>testMethod</methodName>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value>
                <string>Test value 1</string>
            </value>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodCall>
```

response:
(I am using Open HttpRequester to view the response)
browser mode: []

plaintext mode:

Sfdump = window.Sfdump || (function (doc) { var refStyle = doc.createElement('style'), rxEsc = /([.*+?^${}()|[]/\])/g, idRx = /\bsf-dump-\d+-ref[012]\w+\b/, keyHint = 0 <= navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') ? 'Cmd' : 'Ctrl', addEventListener = function (e, n, cb) { e.addEventListener(n, cb, false); }; (doc.documentElement.firstElementChild || doc.documentElement.children[0]).appendChild(refStyle); if (!doc.addEventListener) { addEventListener = function (element, eventName, callback) { element.attachEvent('on' + eventName, function (e) { e.preventDefault = function () {e.returnValue = false;}; e.target = e.srcElement; callback(e); }); }; } function toggle(a, recursive) { var s = a.nextSibling || {}, oldClass = s.className, arrow, newClass; if ('sf-dump-compact' == oldClass) { arrow = '▼'; newClass = 'sf-dump-expanded'; } else if ('sf-dump-expanded' == oldClass) { arrow = '▶'; newClass = 'sf-dump-compact'; } else { return false; } a.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; s.className = newClass; if (recursive) { try { a = s.querySelectorAll('.'+oldClass); for (s = 0; s < a.length; ++s) { if (a[s].className !== newClass) { a[s].className = newClass; a[s].previousSibling.lastChild.innerHTML = arrow; } } } catch (e) { } } return true; }; return function (root, x) { root = doc.getElementById(root); var indentRx = new RegExp('^('+(root.getAttribute('data-indent-pad') || ' ').replace(rxEsc, '\$1')+')+', 'm'), options = {"maxDepth":1,"maxStringLength":160,"fileLinkFormat":false}, elt = root.getElementsByTagName('A'), len = elt.length, i = 0, s, h, t = []; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); for (i in x) { options[i] = x[i]; } function a(e, f) { addEventListener(root, e, function (e) { if ('A' == e.target.tagName) { f(e.target, e); } else if ('A' == e.target.parentNode.tagName) { f(e.target.parentNode, e); } else if (e.target.nextElementSibling && 'A' == e.target.nextElementSibling.tagName) { f(e.target.nextElementSibling, e, true); } }); }; function isCtrlKey(e) { return e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey; } addEventListener(root, 'mouseover', function (e) { if ('' != refStyle.innerHTML) { refStyle.innerHTML = ''; } }); a('mouseover', function (a, e, c) { if (c) { e.target.style.cursor = "pointer"; } else if (a = idRx.exec(a.className)) { try { refStyle.innerHTML = 'pre.sf-dump .'+a[0]+'{background-color: #B729D9; color: #FFF !important; border-radius: 2px}'; } catch (e) { } } }); a('click', function (a, e, c) { if (/\bsf-dump-toggle\b/.test(a.className)) { e.preventDefault(); if (!toggle(a, isCtrlKey(e))) { var r = doc.getElementById(a.getAttribute('href').substr(1)), s = r.previousSibling, f = r.parentNode, t = a.parentNode; t.replaceChild(r, a); f.replaceChild(a, s); t.insertBefore(s, r); f = f.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); t = t.firstChild.nodeValue.match(indentRx); if (f && t && f[0] !== t[0]) { r.innerHTML = r.innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('^'+f[0].replace(rxEsc, '\$1'), 'mg'), t[0]); } if ('sf-dump-compact' == r.className) { toggle(s, isCtrlKey(e)); } } if (c) { } else if (doc.getSelection) { try { doc.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); } catch (e) { doc.getSelection().empty(); } } else { doc.selection.empty(); } } else if (/\bsf-dump-str-toggle\b/.test(a.className)) { e.preventDefault(); e = a.parentNode.parentNode; e.className = e.className.replace(/sf-dump-str-(expand|collapse)/, a.parentNode.className); } }); elt = root.getElementsByTagName('SAMP'); len = elt.length; i = 0; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); len = t.length; for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) { elt = t[i]; if ('SAMP' == elt.tagName) { elt.className = 'sf-dump-expanded'; a = elt.previousSibling || {}; if ('A' != a.tagName) { a = doc.createElement('A'); a.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; elt.parentNode.insertBefore(a, elt); } else { a.innerHTML += ' '; } a.title = (a.title ? a.title+'\n[' : '[')+keyHint+'+click] Expand all children'; a.innerHTML += '▼'; a.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; x = 1; if ('sf-dump' != elt.parentNode.className) { x += elt.parentNode.getAttribute('data-depth')/1; } elt.setAttribute('data-depth', x); if (x > options.maxDepth) { toggle(a); } } else if ('sf-dump-ref' == elt.className && (a = elt.getAttribute('href'))) { a = a.substr(1); elt.className += ' '+a; if (/[[{]$/.test(elt.previousSibling.nodeValue)) { a = a != elt.nextSibling.id && doc.getElementById(a); try { s = a.nextSibling; elt.appendChild(a); s.parentNode.insertBefore(a, s); if (/^[@#]/.test(elt.innerHTML)) { elt.innerHTML += ' ▶'; } else { elt.innerHTML = '▶'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } elt.className += ' sf-dump-toggle'; } catch (e) { if ('&' == elt.innerHTML.charAt(0)) { elt.innerHTML = '…'; elt.className = 'sf-dump-ref'; } } } } } if (0 >= options.maxStringLength) { return; } try { elt = root.querySelectorAll('.sf-dump-str'); len = elt.length; i = 0; t = []; while (i < len) t.push(elt[i++]); len = t.length; for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) { elt = t[i]; s = elt.innerText || elt.textContent; x = s.length - options.maxStringLength; if (0 < x) { h = elt.innerHTML; elt[elt.innerText ? 'innerText' : 'textContent'] = s.substring(0, options.maxStringLength); elt.className += ' sf-dump-str-collapse'; elt.innerHTML = ''+h+' ◀'+ ''+elt.innerHTML+' ▶'; } } } catch (e) { } }; })(document);  pre.sf-dump { display: block; white-space: pre; padding: 5px; } pre.sf-dump span { display: inline; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-compact { display: none; } pre.sf-dump abbr { text-decoration: none; border: none; cursor: help; } pre.sf-dump a { text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; border: 0; outline: none; color: inherit; } pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ellipsis { display: inline-block; overflow: visible; text-overflow: ellipsis; max-width: 5em; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; vertical-align: top; } pre.sf-dump code { display:inline; padding:0; background:none; } .sf-dump-str-collapse .sf-dump-str-collapse { display: none; } .sf-dump-str-expand .sf-dump-str-expand { display: none; }pre.sf-dump, pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-default{background-color:#fff; color:#222; line-height:1.2em; font-weight:normal; font:12px Monaco, Consolas, monospace; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap; position:relative; z-index:100000}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-num{color:#a71d5d}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-const{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-str{color:#df5000}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-cchr{color:#222}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-note{color:#a71d5d}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-ref{color:#a0a0a0}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-public{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-protected{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-private{color:#795da3}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-meta{color:#b729d9}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-key{color:#df5000}pre.sf-dump .sf-dump-index{color:#a71d5d}[]
Sfdump("sf-dump-2001561441")

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.xmlrpc-decode-request.php - This function should be used at your own risk
Anyway what do you expect of this feature? If you're using SOAP you can use SOAP libraries. If you are using JSON - json_decode etc

Comment: I really am a newbie in web services, just about to figure it out. I have to use xml-rpc, because that is what my employer wishes to implement. I know that xml_rpc_decode_request and xml_rpc_encode_request are experimental, but if that was the problem, then, the print_r($request->toArray) would work normally, but it doesn't;

Comment: use `dd($request)` instead of `print_r`

Comment: dd($request) returns some kind of script, which generates an empty array.

Comment: What's in `dd($request->all())` ?

Comment: Please post as much code as you can. Route for this controller, method that you use and request that you sent. And how do you view response? Via some tool?

Comment: If you just viewing the page - there is no request that you sent. Only GET request. You can see response only in some tool like devtools in Chrome or Firefox etc or tool like Postman

Comment: Updated the question, providing some additional info. As i said in the original question, i am using Open HttpRequester plugin for Firefox to both send request and view the response.

Comment: ok, can you post some image of response because I really can't see in this code anything

Comment: I think you can use `dd($request->getContent());` to see request body

Comment: The last one worked, now i am finally able to process the request, thank you.

Comment: If you care about reputation add it as an answer, as it is the correct one.

Comment: ok, thanks. Glad to help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use `$request->getContent();` if you are posting raw data