# Laravel request->all() is empty

Tags: laravel

In Laravel 8, `$request->all()` is not showing dynamic path parameters.

Steps to reproduce:

- Start a new Laravel project with composer, Laravel version 8.61.0.
- Define a route in `routes/api.php` as follows:

```
Route::get('/first/{first}/second/{second}', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->all();
});
```

- Run `php artisan serve` and direct the browser to `http://localhost:8000/api/first/hello/second/world`
- Expect something like the following response: `{"first":"hello","second":"world"}`.  Instead we simply see `[]`.
- Change the route to:

```
Route::get('/first/{first}/second/{second}', function (Request $request) {
    return [
        'first'=>$request->first,
        'second'=>$request->second,
    ];
});
```

- Then we see the expected `{"first":"hello","second":"world"}`

So...why isn't `$request->all()` giving me this response?

Comment: Did you try `json_encode($request->all())` ? Cause $request->all() return an array.

Comment: My question is: why does `$request->all()` return an empty array? `json_encode` does not change that behavior.

Comment: Hey, this is not a request parameters this is a url segment not query parameter. 
if you have a function in controller for this route it will be like 
public function($first, $last);
and you can print those first and last variables.

Comment: According to [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-all-input-data) the `Illuminate\Http\Request` `$request` object should have a method `all()` that gives "all of the incoming request's input data". Maybe I am misunderstanding the docs, but I take "input data" to include "input from a route parameter".

Comment: Hi, did you get a solution/answer for this?

Comment: @AdityaSharma No. It appears `$request->all()` simply does not work as [described](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-all-input-data).

Answer (score 0):

I looked at Laravel doc

[Retrieving All Input Data](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#retrieving-all-input-data)

> You may retrieve all of the incoming request's input data as an
> `array` using the `all` method. This method may be used regardless of
> whether the incoming request is from an HTML form or is an XHR
> request

Means `$request->all()` equal to `$request->input('name', 'email', ....)`

---

instead of `$request->all()` you can try this

```
Route::get('/first/{first}/second/{second}', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request, $first, $second) {
  return [
      'first'=> $first,
      'second'=> $second,
  ];
});
```

---

### UPDATE

You can do it too with (splat operator in PHP)

```
Route::get('/first/{first}/second/{second}', function (Illuminate\Http\Request $request, ...$all) {
  return $all;
});

// returns
[
  "hello",
  "world"
]
```

I hope this helped you,

Happy Coding.

Comment: These suggestions don't address why $request->all() is not working as described in the docs and also don't solve my problem.  The first solution doesn't work because I don't want to know in advance what the request inputs are. The second 'Updated' solution doesn't work because I in fact want to use $request->all() in a middleware, which only receives the $request variable. If there a way to pass the Request parameters to a middleware `handle`?  I excluded the middleware issue from my question for simplicity, because the fact remains that $request->all() seems to not behave as expected.

Comment: `$request->all()`  just works with form inputs or  an XHR request, the answer why  `$request->all()`  not working.

Comment: As I understand you want to get URL parameters inside a middleware? right?

Comment: That's correct.  `$request->segments()` gives me the segments of the url within a middleware, but I want to identify what variables are contained in the url parameter, as defined by a route like `'/first/{firstId}/second/{secondId}'`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `dd($request->all())` statement in Controller, not in closure. In previous Laravel version (version 5 or version 7), that state works in that versions.

Comment: To test your hypothesis, I made a controller `SayHi` with the function `sayHi`and wired it up: `Route::get('/first/{first}/second/{second}', [SayHi::class,'sayHi']);`.  `dd($request->all())` still spits out an empty array.  `dd($request->segments())`, however, correctly returns the segments.  That is the same behavior as in my original example.

Answer (score 0):

don't know why `$request->all()` is empty,  but I used `$request->getContent()` and it returned the data in the body of the request I was looking for.

Credit:
[Laravel empty request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324837/laravel-empty-request)